# Need explanation about a piece of D3.JS code

Tags: typescript, d3.js, charts

I am following an example from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3943967

I got 1 line not working, I am trying to understand it in order to debug it but I'm struggling.

```
   y01z = d3.stack().keys(d3.range(n))(d3.transpose(yz))
```

n is always equal to 4 and yz is a array[]

```
  y01z = d3.stack().keys(d3.range(4))(d3.transpose([]))
```

This is not working either.

[image]
I just copied and paste the example code and encapsulate all the variables in the object "o", the error was already here before that.

My guess is the example code is maybe not a D3 v4 or just not correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by casting with

```
    const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain(<any>[
      d3.min(series, this.stackMin),
      d3.max(series, this.stackMax)
    ]);
```